# How to hide windows service from task manager in windows desktop

Tags: windows-services

I am creating windows service in desktop while running its showing on task manager . So is there any api or any procedure for hide service diagrammatically.can you pls send some sample code for service which can hide from task manager .

Comment: Yes, well, it's going to show in task manager. Why do you want to hide it?

Comment: Could be because it's a malicious, but it could also just be a legitimate security app and this is a (misguided) attempt to stop people from killing it.

Comment: Go somewhere else if you want advice on writing malware.

Comment: The only non-malicious use I can think of is laptop tracking software for phoning home when a laptop is identified as stolen.

Answer (score 4):

No.  TaskManager is designed to list the applications running.  You cannot legitimately hide an app from TaskManager Processes tab.

You could give your app a clever name to disguise it.  But really, there's a security reason that all processes will be listed.

Comment: Technically, the answer isn't "No", but I don't think there is a legitimate reason for wanting this. We'll see.

Comment: Thanks for quick response. So is there any windows service api which can help me for hide service from windows task manager.

Thnaks,
Kamal Ku Behera.

Answer (score 2):

You could write a device driver, they aren't listed in the normal "running processes" lists, only in device manager.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think that there is a way to do this as it will always show up as a process and indeed you'll also need to hide it from the Administrator/Services app. in which case it won't be a windows service as all services must register with the Service Manager in order to run.

The only way in which this could be achieved is by running at the BIOS level or as a separate kernal within which you run the Windows OS.

If you're trying to prevent people from stopping your service then write two services that mutually support each other i.e. automatically kicks off the other service if the first is stopped.

Answer (score 0):

Task Manager shows Services in the Services tab. 
[image]

However, there is a way to avoid it. We change the Service’s Security Descriptor. This is done using [SDDL](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/secauthz/security-descriptor-definition-language) which stands for Security Descriptor Definition Language.

Provided that *serviceName* ([std::wstring](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/wstring/)) holds the name of the Service and *hService* ([HANDLE](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/sysinfo/handles-and-objects)) is a handle to a Service, the following code will hide the service:

```
    PSECURITY_DESCRIPTOR secDescPtr;
    ULONG secDescSize = 0;
    if (ConvertStringSecurityDescriptorToSecurityDescriptor(L"D:(D;;DCWPDTSD;;;IU)(D;;DCWPDTSD;;;SU)(D;;DCWPDTSD;;;BA)(A;;CCSWLOCRRC;;;IU)(A;;CCSWLOCRRC;;;SU)(A;;CCSWRPWPDTLOCRRC;;;SY)(A;;CCDCSWRPWPDTLOCRSDRCWDWO;;;BA)",
        SDDL_REVISION_1,
        &secDescPtr,
        &secDescSize) == TRUE)
    {

        wprintf(L"Security Descriptor conversion ok");
        if (SetServiceObjectSecurity(hService, DACL_SECURITY_INFORMATION, secDescPtr) == TRUE)
        {
            wprintf(L"Service %s hidden",serviceName);
            ret = true;
        }
        else
        {
            switch (GetLastError())
            {
            case ERROR_ACCESS_DENIED:
                wprintf(_T("Service Security setup failed - Access Denied"));
                break;
            case ERROR_INVALID_HANDLE:
                wprintf(_T("Service Security setup failed - Invalid Handle"));
                break;
            case ERROR_INVALID_PARAMETER:
                wprintf(_T("Service Security setup failed - Invalid Parameter"));
                break;
            case ERROR_SERVICE_MARKED_FOR_DELETE:
                wprintf(_T("Service Security setup failed - Service Marked For Delete"));
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    else
    {
        wprintf(_T("Security Descriptor conversion failed"));
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/32744/Driver-to-Hide-Processes-and-Files lies your answer man.

Also search the Web for "direct kernel object manipulation" to understand how you can do it- or read this

http://www.blackhat.com/presentations/win-usa-04/bh-win-04-butler.pdf

or watch this video 
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hcr35ddvjHI

One of the reasons that a skilled hacker takes less than 5 minutes to create a overflow/race condition/dkom/ patching in the code is primarily because of state of knowledge in programmers.

Comment: These solutions used to work 10-15 years ago but not any more.