# How to register a windows service but avoid it being listed in the services console?

Tags: c++, delphi, winapi, windows-7

I know a legitimate Windows Application, a parental control software, that install as a service, but the service is not listed in the service list, the list you see in services.msc.

It is listed in the task manager, though, but not in the server list.

I know it is a server, because it is in the Registry section with all the rest of the services, however, the services.msc console won't list it.

I've researched for days without an answer.

I found this similar question, but in the answers they recommend complicated routs like writing a device driver:
[How to hide windows service from task manager in windows desktop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1558292/how-to-hide-windows-service-from-task-manager-in-windows-desktop)

However, these guys made it with a service.
How do they did it?

This are the Registry Keys:

```
[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\services\ThatTrickySoftwareSrv]
"Type"=dword:00000010
"Start"=dword:00000002
"ErrorControl"=dword:00000001
"ImagePath"=hex(2):22,00
"DisplayName"="Some display name"
"ObjectName"="LocalSystem"
"Description"="Some description"
"FailureActions"=hex:00,00

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\services\ThatTrickySoftwareSrv\Security]
"Security"=hex:01,00
```

Some binary content was truncated for readability.

This is on Windows 7 32bits.

Following Harry Jonhston advice:

```
**sc sdshow "ThatTrickySoftware"**
    D:(D;;DCLCWPDTSD;;;IU)(D;;DCLCWPDTSD;;;SU)(D;;DCLCWPDTSD;;;BA)(A;;CCLCSWLOCRRC;;
;IU)(A;;CCLCSWLOCRRC;;;SU)(A;;CCLCSWRPWPDTLOCRRC;;;SY)(A;;CCDCLCSWRPWPDTLOCRSDRC
WDWO;;;BA)S:(AU;FA;CCDCLCSWRPWPDTLOCRSDRCWDWO;;;WD)
```

So, well, this was expected I guess, though it is not listed as a service, and it runs as a service, because it is automatically started by Windows, but there's no clue anywhere could Windows be running this application.

Also, **note**, the executable is listed in the Process tabs in the TaskManager, however, it is unbreakable, I can't kill it, it just nothing happens if I try to kill the process.

Comment: I've seen some really clever things done using Task Scheduler, including things which appear to work as a service but actually only execute on certain events.

Comment: @JerryDodge it is not in the Task scheduler, I looked up there too. I first manually searched to where this application could be running from, because I thought it was a service, then, I ran autoruns tool, and I couldn't find it with its help either. Then I compared the registry of windows before and after the install and that's where I saw the service. Let me post the keys.

Comment: It would be useful if we knew what that tricky service actually was, if you're at liberty to share it with us. But it has something to do probably with the `FailureActions` and `Security` fields... Did you try adding an identical key/value to your service?

Comment: Reading up on the Registry Entries, I see no mention of the `FailureActions` or `Security` values... http://support.microsoft.com/kb/103000

Comment: @Jerry: looking at existing examples, FailureActions and Security are normal, whether they're documented or not.

Comment: Hi @JerryDodge I was in that microsoft KB article, too :). In my computer there are a few others services that contains the Security Key. Also there are some that has the FailureActions value. I agree there is no information about that in Microsoft site.

Comment: @HarryJohnston Sure, but not finding documentation makes it harder. However that link I shared appears to be applicable to XP, or maybe Vista, doesn't say. I can only tell by the published date.

Comment: @JerryDodge: it's fairly self-explanatory though.  FailureActions must encode the failure actions (ala `sc qfailure`) and Security encodes the ACL of the service.  (It looks like services with the default ACL don't get an entry, which seems a reasonable optimization.)

Comment: @CraigStevensson: could you post the output of `sc sdshow ThatTrickySoftwareSvc` please?

Comment: Hi, Harry, I ran your command, it did respond some output (first I did it wrong and post it, but I've edited my post). So, I think it is a service, right?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

OK, I can reproduce this behaviour: by giving a service the same permissions as those of the mystery service, I can make it disappear from the list in services.msc.

```
sc sdset myservice D:(D;;DCLCWPDTSD;;;IU)(D;;DCLCWPDTSD;;;SU)(D;;DCLCWPDTSD;;;BA)(A;;CCLCSWLOCRRC;;;IU)(A;;CCLCSWLOCRRC;;;SU)(A;;CCLCSWRPWPDTLOCRRC;;;SY)(A;;CCDCLCSWRPWPDTLOCRSDRCWDWO;;;BA)S:(AU;FA;CCDCLCSWRPWPDTLOCRSDRCWDWO;;;WD)
```

So it's all down to the permissions.

OK, let's expand out that security descriptor string.  This is a bit tricky because the mapping between the SDDL permissions and equivalent security manager permissions does not appear to be well documented in MSDN or in the SDK headers; luckily, Wayne Martin has already done the heavy lifting for us and posted the results in the blog entry [Service Control Manager Security for non-admins](http://waynes-world-it.blogspot.co.nz/2009/10/service-control-manager-security-for.html).

```
D: - this part is the DACL, the permissions on the service.
```

Deny entries always come first, which also means they take precedence over the allow entries:

```
(D;;DCLCWPDTSD;;;IU) - deny (D) interactive users (IU) the following rights:
  DC - SERVICE_CHANGE_CONFIG (the right to change the service configuration)
  LC - SERVICE_QUERY_STATUS (the right to query the service status)
  WP - SERVICE_STOP (the right to stop the service)
  DT - SERVICE_PAUSE_CONTINUE (the right to pause and continue the service)
  SD - DELETE (the right to delete the service)
(D;;DCLCWPDTSD;;;SU) - deny services (SU) the same set of rights as above
(D;;DCLCWPDTSD;;;BA) - deny the Administrators group (BA) the same as above
```

The allow entries are just the same as the default permissions.  (They are in a different order, but the order of allow entries is not significant.)

```
(A;;CCLCSWLOCRRC;;;IU) - allow the interactive user the following rights:
  CC - SERVICE_QUERY_CONFIG (the right to query the service configuration)
  LC - overridden by the deny entry
  SW - SERVICE_ENUMERATE_DEPENDENTS (the right to see service dependencies)
  LO - SERVICE_INTERROGATE (the right to send SERVICE_CONTROL_INTERROGATE)
  CR - SERVICE_USER_DEFINED_CONTROL (the right to send a user defined control)
  RC - READ_CONTROL (the right to see the permissions)
(A;;CCLCSWLOCRRC;;;SU) - allow services the following rights:
   same as for the interactive user
(A;;CCLCSWRPWPDTLOCRRC;;;SY) - allow local system the following rights:
   same as for the interactive user, plus:       
   RP - SERVICE_START (the right to start the service)
   WP - overridden by the deny entry for BA
   DT - overridden by the deny entry for BA
(A;;CCDCLCSWRPWPDTLOCRSDRCWDWO;;;BA) - allow the Administrators group:
   same as for local system, plus:
   DC - overridden by the deny entry
   LC - overridden by the deny entry
   SW - overridden by the deny entry
   SD - overridden by the deny entry
   WD - WRITE_DAC (permission to change the permissions)
   WO - WRITE_OWNER (permission to take ownership)
```

Finally, we have the SACL.  This is also unchanged from the default for a service.

```
S:(AU;FA;CCDCLCSWRPWPDTLOCRSDRCWDWO;;;WD)
  S: - indicates that this is a SACL
  AU - indicates that this is an audit entry
  FA - indicates that failed attempts to access the object should be audited
  WD - controls whose failed attempts should be audited; the Everyone SID
  CCDCLCSWRPWPDTLOCRSDRCWDWO - the kinds of access attempts to audit
    - appears to include every right that applies to services
```

So basically that just says "audit all failed attempts to access this service".

It should be possible to significantly simplify those permissions, e.g., by removing all the allow permissions that are overridden by the deny permissions.  In fact, it seems likely the only access permission you would really need is SERVICE_START and perhaps SERVICE_QUERY permission for local system, and maybe not even those. :-)

On the other hand, the complexity of the permissions doesn't really matter, so it probably isn't worth the effort involved in testing the changes.

---

PS: to restore the default permissions you can say:

```
sc sdset myservice D:(A;;CCLCSWRPWPDTLOCRRC;;;SY)(A;;CCDCLCSWRPWPDTLOCRSDRCWDWO;;;BA)(A;;CCLCSWLOCRRC;;;IU)(A;;CCLCSWLOCRRC;;;SU)S:(AU;FA;CCDCLCSWRPWPDTLOCRSDRCWDWO;;;WD)
```

Comment: Yessssssssss!! that did it....:) I tried that to my service as well and it disappeared from the list..... however... what are we doing here? and what is that ugly string?

Comment: I would have never been able to write this myself, that is some really funky syntax.

Comment: [Security Descriptor Definition Language.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa379567%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)  If I get a chance I'll add to my answer tomorrow to fill in exactly what each part of the string is doing ...

Comment: I'd appreciate a further explanation about that security string.....in the meantime, where did you get the string that restore the default permissions?

Comment: @Craig I'm sure Harry is somewhat familiar with at least understanding the syntax, it would take me weeks to learn that even with the documentation.

Comment: @Craig: to determine the default permissions I ran `sc sdshow` on a service whose permissions hadn't been modified.

Comment: @HarryJohnston thank you for a very thorough answer. That indeed work when it comes to hiding the Service from the Task Manager's "services" tab, but not from a well known tool named autoruns.exe. Is that so?

Comment: @MichaelHaephrati, I haven't checked, but that would be unsurprising.  Autoruns is designed as a security tool, and was written by Mark Russinovich who is a particularly clever man even by Microsoft's standards, so it is probably very careful not to allow itself to miss anything - or at least not for trivial reasons like the security descriptor.

Comment: @HarryJohnston, I learned a lot from Mark Russinovich's programming books, since 1998, so I certainly agree about that :) That being said, ProcessExplorer (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/process-explorer) won't show such Windows Service once it becomes hidden.

Answer (score 0):

Provided that *serviceName* ([std::wstring](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/wstring/)) holds the name of the Service and *hService* ([HANDLE](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/sysinfo/handles-and-objects)) is a handle to a Service, the following code will hide the service:

```
    PSECURITY_DESCRIPTOR secDescPtr;
    ULONG secDescSize = 0;
    if (ConvertStringSecurityDescriptorToSecurityDescriptor(L"D:(D;;DCWPDTSD;;;IU)(D;;DCWPDTSD;;;SU)(D;;DCWPDTSD;;;BA)(A;;CCSWLOCRRC;;;IU)(A;;CCSWLOCRRC;;;SU)(A;;CCSWRPWPDTLOCRRC;;;SY)(A;;CCDCSWRPWPDTLOCRSDRCWDWO;;;BA)",
        SDDL_REVISION_1,
        &secDescPtr,
        &secDescSize) == TRUE)
    {

        wprintf(L"Security Descriptor conversion ok");
        if (SetServiceObjectSecurity(hService, DACL_SECURITY_INFORMATION, secDescPtr) == TRUE)
        {
            wprintf(L"Service %s hidden",serviceName);
            ret = true;
        }
        else
        {
            switch (GetLastError())
            {
            case ERROR_ACCESS_DENIED:
                wprintf(_T("Service Security setup failed - Access Denied"));
                break;
            case ERROR_INVALID_HANDLE:
                wprintf(_T("Service Security setup failed - Invalid Handle"));
                break;
            case ERROR_INVALID_PARAMETER:
                wprintf(_T("Service Security setup failed - Invalid Parameter"));
                break;
            case ERROR_SERVICE_MARKED_FOR_DELETE:
                wprintf(_T("Service Security setup failed - Service Marked For Delete"));
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    else
    {
        wprintf(_T("Security Descriptor conversion failed"));
    }
```