# How can I prevent users change the start type on my Windows Service?

Tags: windows, command-line, windows-services, admin

I have developed an windows service in WCF and I dont want that users can edit properties in Windows Services list and disable it. I want to disable this option like others services do.

Is it possible do it with some command line?

Comment: You can change permissions with `sc sdset`.  (Of course the user can change them back again if they know how.  Unless the user doesn't have admin privilege, in which case the default is that they can't change anything.)

Comment: Yes. I know that the way this is. But can you tell me which option to use on sdset? I've tried several, I'm reading the documentation and i not found the right way to give deny this option.

Comment: There's an example of using `sdset` in [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/25736814/886887).  The first command shown would quite possibly meet your needs as-is, but if you need to tweak it, the rest of the answer should give you the information you need.